# How do I fix this Apache Airflow Error? "[Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Tags: airflow

I'm new to Airlfow, but my understanding is that airflow copies each DAG to a temp directory before it executes it. It is my guess that it is this temp directory that cannot be found, hence the error. The strange thing about this, however, is that the configuration has not changed. This error seems to have come out of nowhere.

The last successful run of the dag outputted this log line:

```
[2020-04-02 12:00:11,216] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-04-02 12:00:11,216] {configuration.py:299} WARNING - section/key [worker/host_temporary_directory] not found in config
[2020-04-02 12:00:11,217] {operator.py:398} INFO - Making host meta dir: /tmp/airflow/airflowtmp9rgc50mu/__AIRFLOW_META__
```

The first failure outputted this line instead:

```
[2020-05-07 10:05:24,919] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-05-07 10:05:24,919] {configuration.py:299} WARNING - section/key [worker/host_temporary_directory] not found in config
[2020-05-07 10:05:24,919] {taskinstance.py:1051} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/airflow/airflowtmpr7d1_wdd'
```

It's as if operator.py failed to make the directory... but why?

The dates are a month apart, because this instance is a dev instance that we keep the jobs turned off when we're not testing. This instance has sat idle and untouched for a month. Now we go to turn the jobs back on and we get this error.

I know I can set the temp directory in the configuration file, but it should be creating the temp directory on it's own.

Any help would be appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted this... I restarted the worker node and everything works without error.

When in doubt, rebout.